# autospec can't run tests after touching a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rspec

I've got two files in app/views/users

-rw-r--r--  1 create.html.erb
-rw-r--r--@ 1 new.html.erb

With autospec running and all my tests passing, I touch 'new.html.erb' and and growl notifies my that my tests can't run and autospec outputs:

0 examples, 0 failures

If I start autospec again all my tests pass.

If I touch 'create.html.erb' nothing happens. My tests continue to run.

Note the ampersand in the output of ls. I don't know what that means but it gets added after autospec runs.

Can anyone help me with this confusing error? I am a rspec/rails noob.

Many thanks.

EDIT:

I noticed the tests were running against:

/spec/views/users/new.html.erb_spec.rb

I see that [this tutorial](http://railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial?version=2.3#cha:static_pages) (which I recommend) advises to delete these files:

"By the way, I’m not partial to separate tests for views, which I’ve found to be quite brittle, so let’s remove them, together with the rarely used helper spec:"

`$ rm -rf spec/views

$ rm -f spec/helpers/pages_helper_spec.rb`

Comment: Do you have anything in `/spec/views/users/create.html.erb_spec.rb`

Comment: Nope. But I think my error is not an error. I think I do not understand rspec enough yet and I am misinterpreting the results.